# Microsoft security center api filter not working

Tags: powershell, windows-defender

I'm attempting to use this URI to find a specific machine ID so then we can query for the most recent logged on user. When I run this I get an output of all the devices in defender. I'm stuck and not sure where to go from here

https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines?$filter=computerDnsName eq 'computer name goes here"

Answer (score 0):

Find the machine id and use this api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/get-machine-log-on-users?view=o365-worldwide

[https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines/'machine](https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines/%27machine) id'/logonuser

Answer (score 0):

To find the ID based on device name use this API call.

https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines?$filter=computerDnsName eq 'Device Name goes here'. Once you get the device name you can then do the logged on user look up using this.

https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines/id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation it seems more than likely that the problem with some id:s not matching the value found in the UI only affected some devices which may have been registered more than once due to being cloned (we use SCCM). I think for most devices this works as expected

---

The problem here is that the id you get for the machines from this api: https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines, may differ from the id you need in the other api: [https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines/{id}](https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines/%7Bid%7D). So I think this is a valid question and as of now I'm unsure of the answer.

In powershell this works:

```
$tenantId = '****' # Paste your directory (tenant) ID here
$clientId = '****' # Paste your application (client) ID here
$appSecret = '****' # Paste the thumbprint of your certificate here

$resourceAppIdUri = 'https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com'
$oAuthUri = "https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
$authBody = [Ordered] @{
  resource = $resourceAppIdUri
  client_id = $clientId
  client_secret = $appSecret
  grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}
$authResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $oAuthUri -Body $authBody -ErrorAction Stop
$token = $authResponse.access_token

# Create the headers for the API request
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}    
$uri = "https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines?`$filter=computerDnsName eq 'name.domain.com'"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get
$id = $response.value[0].id
```

And that will give you and id say (005067aa02b68b884f2c2cf3ba2e678b8c717299), but not necessarily the id you want, there is no "machine id" returned and the "aadDeviceId" cannot be used, and it's also sometimes empty. The id returned is somethimes not the same as the id listed as "Device id" in the Defender GUI (which is the id you need for the second query).If this is the case the query will return an empty result:

```
$uri = "https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines/005067aa02b68b884f2c2cf3ba2e678b8c717299"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get
```

If someone has a working example I would be very interested in seeing it and trying it myself. I have the same problem with this api: [https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines/{id}/software](https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/machines/%7Bid%7D/software). I don't know how to get the correct id reliably, except copying it from the GUI. This seems like a bug in the API or I'm missing something obvious.

I've opened as issue for this on Github: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/microsoft-365-docs/issues/12717#issuecomment-1708068386

Comment: I edited the answer after finding out that I indeed sometimes get the correct ID.

Comment: After further investigation it seems more than likely that the problem with some id:s not matching the value found in the UI only affected some devices which may have been registered more than once due to being cloned (we use SCCM). I think for most devices this works as expected.